# api_key SAM deployment does not apply Open Api 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, openapi, api-key, aws-sam

I am using sam templates for my deployment and I do NOT specify the ApiKeyRequired for either the API or the Functions (since my understanding is that the sam template will not override the api key configuration defined in an external definition body) and am trying to define that in the body defintion contained in in the open api spec I create. The only way I have been able to get the api_key to get applied selectively to each of my methods/endpoints is to use an Open API 2 instead of Open Api 3.

In my Open Api 2 version, on endpoints that need the api key, I have this on the endpoints that need the key:

```
security:
      - api_key: []
:
:
```

and then this:

```
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "x-api-key"
    in: "header"
```

This works and the sam deploy appropriately applies the api_key to the endpoints that I need it on.

If I use Open Api 3, however, the api key does NOT get applied:

```
security:
      - api_key: []
:
:

components:
securitySchemes:
    api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "x-api-key"
    in: "header"
    "x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source" : "HEADER"
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to get the api_key to be applied using an Open Api 3 doc? All my other APIs use the 3 spec and not really wanting to use 2 just because I can't get a 3 to deploy correctly.